# Get an attribute of the model from ModelForm without the instance (overriding __init__)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I have a MultipleChoiceField and for displaying the values that had been previous selected in the admin, I have to override method **init** from a ModelForm. I have the following class with its form:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    contract = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CONTRACT_CHOICES = (
        ('scholar', _(u'Scholar')),
        ('freelance', _(u'Freelance')),
        ('contract', _(u'Contract')),
        ('volunteer', _(u'Volunteer'))
    )
    contract = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CONTRACT_CHOICES)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        initial = kwargs.get('initial',{})
        initial['contract'] = ['scholar', 'contract', 'freelance'] #Here I would have to be able to get the attribute contract from the Profile class, not this list
        kwargs['initial'] = initial
        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

With the `initial['contract']=['scholar','contract','freelance']` works (this values are shown as selected) but I have to achieve this with the attribute contract from Profile. I know that you can access to the model from a ModelForm with the attribute *instance*, but there's one problem: you can only have access to *instance* once the native method of init is called. And in this case, I have to call it later because otherwise it doesn't work for me. I already have tried to do it the following way:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['contract'].initial = self.instance.contract
```

But that doesn't work (it shows no errors but the selected attributes doesn't appear as selected). And furthermore, the following doesn't work either:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['contract'].initial = ['scholar', 'contract', 'freelance']
```

It has only worked as the first way, but with the problem that I don't know how to access to the attribute contract.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think you only have the instance after you've called `super`? If it was passed on instantiation, it'll be in `kwargs`.

Comment: I have tried with `instance = kwargs.get('instance',{})` and then `initial['contract'] = instance.contract` but has no effect (no error but not displaying selected options) @DanielRoseman